# What is decltype(x) inside a lambda supposed to return when x is captured by reference?

Tags: c++, lambda, reference, language-lawyer, decltype

The following program compiles with trunk versions of Clang and GCC:

```
#include <type_traits>

auto main() -> int
{
    auto x = 42;
    [&x] { static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(x), int>::value, "!"); };
}
```

However, the static assert fails with VC12 and VC14, where `decltype(x)` evaluates to `int&` rather than `int`.

I can see why this is happening: the compiler-generated closure type for the lambda has a data member of reference type which is bound to `x` upon construction. `decltype(x)` then refers to this data member and gives `int&` as a result.

Clang and GCC, on the other hand, seem to behave as if no data member were generated, and the *id-expression* `x` refers directly to the captured variable.

Paragraph [[expr.prim.lambda]/18](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#18) of the C++ Standard says that:

> [...] It is unspecified whether additional unnamed non-static data members are declared in the closure type for entities captured by reference.

This seems to imply the behavior is implementation-defined, but what I find more likely is that I'm missing something here. What is the correct behavior supposed to be and where does the Standard mandates it?